# Play audio in the background of Firefox extension popup

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, browser-extension

I've been working on an add-on for Firefox and when opening the pop-up of the add-on, it needs to play an audio file. It works perfectly while the popup is open, but the audio stops after the popup is minimized.

Comment: Its because popup window is `closed` not `minimized`, can you tell for how long you want to play the audio after popup is even closed and what exactly you want to play?

Comment: It should be played on a loop until the user opens the popup again and manually pauses it.

Comment: Have you tried to place the code in the background script?

Comment: Yes, I tried with background script and background page too, but nothing.

Comment: You can open a pin tab in Firefox and play and pause song in that tab from popup. In pinned tab, you can inject a player and manage the song controls from popup using messaging.

Comment: Yeah I did it with the pinned tab solution, I couldn't find a way to get that popup to do that. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

The popup window will be closed when the user leaves it.

Not a perfect, but you can refer to https://github.com/ripper2hl/whitenoisefy.

Comment: What is that, exactly?

Comment: @TheAdnan Uh, I might have wrongly think it was running a script on active tab to play it, but check again found no sign of this.